# Posting in blazor returns exception stating that "The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32."

Tags: c#, json, blazor, .net-standard, jwt

I am new to Blazor and I am encountering the following issue when trying to post for data with an authentication token : at the time of the API call, an exception is lifted with the message "***The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 1.***"

Here's the code in my blazor page's code-behind :

```
public partial class ContactCreate : AuthenticatedPageBase
{
    [Inject]
    public IContactDataService ContactDataService { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public ICountryDataService CountryDataService { get; set; }

    public Contact.Post Model { get; set; } = new Contact.Post();

    protected string CountryIdString { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    protected string TokenString { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    protected List<Country.ListItem> Countries { get; set; } = new List<Country.ListItem>();

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
        Countries = (await CountryDataService.GetCountryListAsync(Token.Token)).ToList();
        TokenString = Token.Token;
    }

    protected async Task HandleValidSubmit()
    {
        try
        {
            Model.CountryId = int.Parse(CountryIdString);
            var response = await ContactDataService.PostContactAsync(TokenString, Model);
            NavManager.NavigateTo("/contacts");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }
    }

    protected void HandleInvalidSubmit()
    {
        ErrorMessage = "Le formulaire n'est pas valide. Veuillez réessayer.";
    }
}
```

and here's the relevant code in the data service :

```
public async Task<int> PostContactAsync(string token, Contact.Post model)
{
    var response = await PostAuthenticatedAsync<int>(token, Url, model);
    return response;
}

public async Task<T> PostAuthenticatedAsync<T>(string token, string url, object model)
{
    var jsonBody = model.ToJson();
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri(HttpClient.BaseAddress.ToString() + url),
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        Content = jsonBody
    };
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
    var response = await HttpClient.SendAsync(request);
    return await response.FromJson<T>(Options);
}
```

...and the extension method that serializes the object into json :

```
public static StringContent ToJson(this object o)
{
    return new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(o), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
}
```

Here's the object model that I'm passing through :

```
public class Contact
{
    public class Post
    {
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
        public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(20)]
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(60)]
        public string Locality { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And, finally, here's the API method that I'm trying to reach :

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostContact(Contact.Post model)
{
    try
    {
        var createdId = await _contactRepository.CreateAsync(model);
        return Ok(new { Id = createdId });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(new { ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Any idea what is happening or what actual exception lies behind this cryptic error message ?

P.S. : I know that there is a question with that exact exception message but it concerns .NET Core while I'm targeting .NET Standard 2.1. I've read it and it visibly doesn't apply to this case.

Comment: And what is the `response`, specifically what is the JSON that is being returned?  And exactly where is the exception being thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning an int (the Id). You're returning an anonymous object with an int property named Id.
Try

```
return Ok(createdId);
```

Comment: Indeed there it was, I had forgotten to modify that return statement. I didn't pay attention to it because the breakpoint on my API controller method wasn't reached for some reason.